# How to correct the output of the following code?

Tags: javascript, html

when executing, the `<p>` inside `"demo"` and the `document.write("hello")` are displayed after the output of the for loop. I want both the statements to print before the `for` loop, how can I do that?

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="main">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
  <p>11</p> <!-- wrong o/p here -->
<script>
  document.write("hello"); // and also wrong here
  var x = document.getElementById("main");
  var y = x.getElementsByTagName("p");
  var len = y.length
  for(var i=0;i<=len;i++) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += y[i].innerHTML + " <br>"; 
  } 
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
1

2

3

1 
2 
3 

11

hello
```

Comment: document.write is generally not advised...

Comment: The "p" is not inside "demo", it is after it because "demo" is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use document.write.

Just output using:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "whatever";
```

whenever you want in code. And get rid of `<p>11</p>` just do all output in code.